# Suspected sock-puppetry

Tags: support, sock-puppets, multiple-accounts

I was a bit suspicious about [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2863878/help-me-understand-javascriptvoidnull/2863895#2863895) to a question, there's some technically incorrect information in it that I thought an expert might have picked up on.  Regardless, I pointed it out yet the answer still kept getting upvotes and the user decided to brush off my comment instead of fixing said information (it would only have taken 1 edit!).

Despite my suspicions I decided to brush it off as other users going with the status-quo and upvoting.  Then I noticed two comments were left by the user and both comments were upvoted almost instantly.  This raised my suspicions again, so I replied to the original comment.

Quite quickly I got another reply comment from the user, followed by another reply comment from another user agreeing with him and both comments were upvoted very quickly and close together.

The users are [Sarfraz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/139459/sarfraz) and [phpBOY](https://stackoverflow.com/users/272718/phpboy).  If you look at the latter's profile, you'll see that Sarfraz has quite a lot of involvement in phpBOY's questions -- his name appears on 5 out of the 8 questions in the profile.

Of course, this could be one huge coincidence and it could be my general annoyance at the blatant ignorance this guy has shown on several occasions including this one.

---

Another interesting thing is [this revision](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/2306826/revisions) to phpBOY's question.  The revision just removes an ellipsis from the end of the question.  Chalk it up to a pointless edit or maybe it was to grow one edit closer to that (not-so) elusive Strunk & White badge?

Comment: Because some people can get angry and could play downvote havoc, I suggest next time you flag the suspicious post for moderator attention. But +1 for posting it.

Comment: @Ladybug Killer: good point, I didn't think about that and I will do so in the future.

Comment: suspecting someone is bad, but I used to think many of his posts are under conspiracy. I was thought the same thing when I saw that post actually, but I don't want any problem with anyone, so I am just ignoring.

Comment: @S.Mark: I completely agree with you there, I've been suspicious for a while now.

Comment: Regarding bumping/editing, thats his normal behavior, see Roger's comment on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1984213) question and see the [revision](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/1984213/revisions#rev90be7655-b8cb-4ec3-9955-e5c02421965c) history from 4 to 10

Comment: @S.Mark: Wow, that's really bad.

Comment: Wow, phpBOY got deleted since you asked this question, or is it just me?

Comment: @Benjol You're right.

Comment: And Looks like his rep-cap is broken by ~70, so you were right Andy! But I am going to run away! (before he comes to meta) :D

Comment: @Benjol: indeed, phpBOY must have been a sock puppet, he's gone.  Now I wonder, though, if there are others.

Comment: @S.Mark: haha :-)

Comment: @S.Mark: [He is already at meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/140077/sarfraz-ahmed). Don't know if he brought his sock puppets here though...

Comment: Hey, what did you do to my phpBOY? He was just... carrying my luggage. [I swear!](http://www.miaminewtimes.com/2010-05-06/news/christian-right-leader-george-rekers-takes-vacation-with-rent-boy/)

Comment: @Questions: lol that is hilarious.

Comment: I'm not sure you can rule out all other explanations to the connection between accounts than sock puppetry. Asaf Karagila commented on a lot of my answers on Mathematics Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 4):

### Grab your pitchforks and torches! Lets go get them sockpyppets!

Comment: honestly, I wish there was a better way to stop this practice. I see a lot of questions where the best answer is either not chosen or get's no votes at all. I try to help where I can by down/up voting appropriately but I only have one vote to give. It should be that way for everybody.

Comment: Amen to that :-)